# Showing complex numbers being equal without using argument properties

Tags: complex-numbers

If we are given two lines given by : $z \bar{a}_{1}+\bar{z} a_{1}+b_{1}=0$
$z \bar{a}_{2}+\bar{z} a_{2}+b_{2}=0$ for them to be parallel/perpendicular they must have their real slopes equal or product = -1 . As we know it implies $\frac{-Re(a_1)}{Im(a_1)} = \frac{-Re(a_2)}{Im(a_2)}$ for parallel how does this imply that $\frac{a_1}{-\bar{a}_1}$ = $\frac{a_2}{-\bar{a}_2}$ ? Without going into taking argument of the complex numbers ? By argument i can think of taking two points each on both lines and showing that the real slopes condition being that imples the required condition .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, $x+iy$ and $u+iv$ are two complex numbers.  Prove
$$
\frac{-x}{y}=\frac{-u}{v}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\frac{x+iy}{-x+iy}= \frac{u+iv}{-u+iv}
$$

This is easy: Assume
$$
\frac{-x}{y}=\frac{-u}{v}\quad\text{so that}\quad\frac{x}{y}=\frac{u}{v}
$$
In particular, $y \ne 0$ and $v \ne 0$.
Then
$$
\frac{x+iy}{-x+iy} = \frac{x/y+i}{-x/y+i} = \frac{u/v+i}{-u/v+i}
=\frac{u+iv}{-u+iv}
$$